# Google API: ConnectionResetError when refreshing token

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

The following code fails with the error 
`"ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"` on the line `http = credentials.refresh(http)`

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
import pickle

#credentials is a GoogleCredentials object generated during the auth flow
credentials = pickle.load(open("credentials.pickle", "rb"))
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.refresh(http)
service = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http)
```

Running the code with `http = credentials.authorize(http)`, instead of `.refresh`, and it works completely fine.  I'm at a complete loss at this stage as to how to resolve this, any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turns out the issue was with the URI stored in the credentials.  
The issue was resolved via  

   `from oauth2client import GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI  
    credentials = GoogleCredentials(None, client_id, client_secret,credentials.refresh_token, None, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, None)  
    http = httplib2.Http()  
    http = credentials.authorize(http)`

Comment: Maybe this page is helpful. [ConnectionResetError missing in retry · Issue #558 · googleapis/google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/558)